# Excel formula SUMIF not working correctly

Tags: excel, formula, sumifs

I have a question on Excel sumifs formula. Please refer to the picture below.

1. Why is the sum of category ">= USD 1 Bil" summing all the values in the value column?
2. Why is the sum of category "<USD 1 Bil" summing the values of categories ">= USD 1 Bil" and "<USD 1 Bil"?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

[image: EXCEL SUMIF QN]

Answer (score 0):

The issue arises because you are using operators such as >, >=, < etc. Use categories in words and it should work as expected.

Screenprint below for your reference

[image: Sumifs]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I was curious as to why this is happening.. and not so much about how to get around it ..

Comment: SUMIFS supports logical operators and wildcards for partial matching hence it might be that excel is performing a logical operation when it finds a logical operation.